# What is a U2E1 socket?

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, sockets, macbook-air, intel-core-i5

I have a 2011 MacBook Air running Ubuntu 14.04 and would like to find out the CPU socket through software methods. To do so, I'm running `sudo dmidecode -t 4`, which yields, among other things, this:

```
Handle 0x000A, DMI type 4, 35 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: U2E1
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Other
    Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
    ID: A7 06 02 00 FF FB EB BF
    Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2467M CPU @ 1.60GHz
    Voltage: 0.0 V
    External Clock: Unknown
    Max Speed: 1600 MHz
    Current Speed: 1625 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: ZIF Socket
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x000C
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x000D
    L3 Cache Handle: 0x000E
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2467M CPU @ 1.60GHz
    Part Number: Not Specified
```

I did find out something about ZIF sockets, and apparently they relate to the insertion technology (so it's not really the answer I'm looking for). I could not find any information about `U2E1` sockets. I believe I'm dealing with either a Sandy Bridge or an Arrandale microarchitecture, but I'd still like to confirm it through the Terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly? I think that the information you're getting is incorrect.

1. [Officially intel *only* sells this processor in one socket type](http://ark.intel.com/products/56858/Intel-Core-i5-2467M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_30-GHz) - the FCBGA1023 or BGA1023, which is soldered on, and its a sandy bridge based model.
2. All macbook airs have soldered on processors -[including the 2011 models](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-i5-1.6-11-mid-2011-specs.html). Even the core 2 based ones had a custom, soldered on processor
3. The contemporary socket was the [socket G2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_G2), and intel didn't seem to use any other socket types in that era.

I'd also add nearly *every* modern, post slot processor is probably ZIF - with older ones you had PGA with a locking lever, with modern ones you have LGA with the cage. In short, DMIdecode isn't really giving you accurate information in any sense.  As a soldered in chip, while there may be zero insertation force from the pick and place machine, removal and replacement may require considerably more force.

<strike>I suspect the U2E1 socket is roughly as mythical as a daylight loving grue, riding a unicorn into battle.</strike>

Interestingly dmidecode identifies my atom 230 as a core 2 solo family, so clearly there's issues with implimentation  (hell, no, its an in order design!)

Edit: Turns out that there's a marking saying U1PR next to the processor (thanks breakthrough!) - so it does designate the *physical* location of the processor, though it dosen't give you any clue to what it is, socketwise. Nonetheless some of the other data is still incorrect, and its quite useless for your specific needs

Comment: I guess that could indeed be the case. Just tested it into a desktop PC and all I got as "Socket Designation" was "CPU 1". I guess I should find another reliable way to discover socket types on Linux.

Comment: Interestingly on my atom (which has a soldered in processor), its designated as U1PR, and upgrade as "other"

Comment: Maybe the "U" number is a reference designator on the motherboard: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25308/what-do-the-pcb-markings-mean

Comment: That seems to be the case actually. Edited to reflect it